# Android Library to convert ESRI Shapefiles to GeoJSON

Tags: shapefile, geojson, ogr2ogr, android

I'm building an Android App for display ESRI Shapefiles but unfortunately, there are only a few free SDKs which support Shapefiles.
Most of them working with GeoJSON, so now I'm looking for an Android Library to convert my Shapefiles to GeoJSON.

Is there any ready to use solution for this problem?
I don't need any standalone tool

Comment: I have no experience with Android, but i could imagine that mapshaper (https://mapshaper.org/) could be worth a look. It provides a very useful CLI.

Comment: The conversion process has to be integrated into my application and it should be working offline.

Comment: possibly https://github.com/paamand/GDAL4Android

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no UNIX OS and I don't even know what ninja, ant, and swing are.